# Changing Heroku folder when creating app in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, web-applications, heroku, wampserver

So I'm new to Heroku and I have a little problem. I use WAMPP to test my webapp in my local machine and as you know the project MUST be in the www folder. When I create an Heroku app in Eclipse it immediately is created in c:\users\myname\git\heroku\appname and I DON'T want that!

Is simple, I want to all my Heroku apps to be created in a folder in the WAMPP www folder and, if possible, to change the GIT folder to be inside that www folder so then I can test my project in my local machine also.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can just move the directory and then import an existing project in Eclipse.  Make sure you tell Eclipse not to copy the contents into the workspace.